# How would I hide a form and display thank you content in the same area - drupal 6

Tags: 6, forms

I've been trying to get to grips with the form api, 
I'm currently trying to hide a form after it has been submitted and to display a thank you template in the same area as the form was in.

Hoping someone might have an answer.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to stay on the same page without leaving and using the submit handler with a `drupal_set_message()`?

Answer (score 0):

Or use $form_state['rebuild'] in the submit handler and check for submitted values in the form builder. That way you can display the form the first time the user hit's the page, and after submission you display your message. This is something like a multistep form, so you could take any of the numerous tutorials for multistep forms in drupal.
Also have look at the official example in [form_example_tutorial.inc](http://drupalcode.org/project/examples.git/blob/6.x-1.x:/form_example/form_example_tutorial.inc#l340)